# Show time after data loading of table

Tags: html, angular6

I have a HTML table which renders one big JSON object of 1 MB file, I would like inform user that how big the object was and how much time it took to display data in Angular 6 application, any pointer please.

The incoming data could be vary based on service.

The line should say, the object which was binded to table HTML was *x* MB and it took *y* second to load data after table finishes of displaying data in HTML.

In face we are doing performance testing of big objects so based on that we are gonna do some stuff from services.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create variable with current time before making request do API, something like
   `const requestStart = new Date()`
2. Make request
3. When response return from API, get `Content-Length` header (I don't know what library you use to get requests, so I cannot help with how to get headers from it) and assign it to some another variable - it will give you file size
4. Subtract current date with `requestStart` date - it will give you time difference

Comment: This is service but just assigned variable which holds mock data like Object1=[{"namem":"test", "class":"first"}], and I am using this service mock data directly by assigning services into component I just need to know how much time it took to bind the data, not the how bing was the attachment.